# How to use a service to call a function in a grandchild component

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Full code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iphgxf

How can I access a method from a grandchild component? I'm trying to use a service to solve this, but I don't know how to put the finishing touches on it given my following situation:

I'm trying to implement a CanDeactivateGuard to prevent a user from navigating away from a page if there is unsaved data (https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes). I'm using the same approach in this guide where I have a canDeactivate method in my page component that gets called by the guard's canDeactivate method.

My problem is that the component for my entity/:id route is a container component, and my presentation component that holds the form data is a grand-child to the route component. I need access to the form in the entity-detail component for the canDeactivate() logic. I need my route component's canDeactivate function to either access another canDeactivate function on the entity-detail component or have access to the form data to perform the validation.

I'm using a similar architecture to @ngrx example-app (see book module) for my entity/:id route (mapped to view-entity-page) where I have a view-entity-page container component responsible for mapping router params to a 'Select' entity action in @ngrx/store. This component has as a child, selected-entity-page, which is responsible for working with @ngrx/store to pass the entity data to the actual presentation component, entity-detail. This may be overkill, but it's what I have for now...

Comment: You route component is responsible for knowing if the user can leave the route. I suppose you will have to delegate to the child components by injecting them in their parent. (`@ViewChild(ComponentType) child: ComponentType)`. Alternative would be keeping the 'unchanged' form state in a service which would be called on each input event from the grandchild, or keeping it in your application state (ngrx store).

Answer (score 0):

Following the container pattern, you could define an output property (event) in the grandchild that notified its parent when the data changed. That parent (child) would then also need to define an Output property (event) that notified its parent (the grandparent). That way the grandparent would have the information needed by the route guard.

An alternate approach would be to add the "dataChanged" property to the store so that the child could dispatch an action and set that property. The guard could then read the data from the store or the grandparent can read it from the store and provide it to the guard.